# Can't install gem with cygwin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cygwin, chef-infra

I installed `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [x86_64-cygwin]`, from cygwin package.

Then I tried to install `chef` by `gem install chef --verbose`, and got this errors.

```
GET http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
304 Not Modified
GET http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET http://rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.9.6.gemspec.rz
302 Moved Temporarily
```

I tried other gems, but the result are looks like all same.
What should I do to use command `gem install xxx`?

Comment: Do you really need the Gem of Chef? Are you aware of the fact that there is an installer for windows shipping all the prerequisites?

Comment: I didn't know there is a windows installer, Thanks. But I want to install after `chef` also `knife-solo` that seems to be missing in this installer package `http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.msi`.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer in general.

Can you try to download the .gem in question manually, and see if you can install from the commandline?

The .gem file can be downloaded from https://rubygems.org/gems/chef at the download link.

Once you have it local, you can run "gem install *.gem" if you are in the same directory.

Comment: When I try install from local package, I get some compile errors. I looks like not working in this way also.